# php openid: Why does the library accept some usernames and others cause errors?

Tags: php, openid

been playing with http://openidenabled.com/php-openid/trunk/examples/consumer and tried the following:

flim.blogspot.com

flimcc.blogspot.com

The first works, the second doesn't. I don't really understand why that is?

Cheers
flim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't this because the first URL resolves to a blog, and the second one doesn't?  The technical reason that this fails as "not a valid OpenID" is because the URL that returns the blog contains this line in the source:

```
<link rel="openid.server" href="http://www.blogger.com/openid-server.g" />
```

The other doesn't.

Comment: yea, you're right :) Sorry, should have thought of that myself